# Mindtouch dream framework UI composition

Tags: asp.net, uicomponents, mindtouch

Has anyone use Mindtouch's dream framework in conjunction with a asp.net frontend?  It seems like all component on the page needs to be client side composited where each component is making a call back to the dream server for rendering another tiny snippet of html.  Wouldn't that be bad in term of client performance?  Is there any way to do server side UI composition using the dream framework?

Comment: With the speed increases in javascript engines, and the revival in clientside scripting (because javascript was always a great language, people just use it badly), having clientside components that use server to persist data and execute business logic (and other non-view concerns) is perfectly feasible.  Rest services also lends itself well to this. Of course you would need to be comfortable with developing in javascript.   Added a comment, because it doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

MindTouch Dream is meant as an REST API first building block. The granularity of your REST services is up to you, so whether you need to run back and forth to the Dream over and over for your UI, depends purely on your API design.

If you happen to host Dream inside of ASP.NET and use the Plug class, the http requests to the API won't actually hit the wire but are dispatched in process, avoiding a lot of the overhead, but you need to be aware that you've now tied tiers together, since if you design based on that performance improvement and then split the tiers in the future, you are going to have a nasty surprise.